# group records based on field count unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting, grep

I'm having a tough time dealing with a file in Unix. Can someone give me directions on to how to deal with this? Thanks in advance

My file's field count is not consistent. I'm trying to gather all the records which has X number of fields.

when I did a awk check on the file based on the delimiter I found that a big % of my records having 19 fields. So I wanted to quarantine those records and make it a separate file.

file : x_orbit.txt

records : 1000

comma delimeter

```
cat x_orbit.txt |  awk --field-separator=',' '{print NF}' | sort -n| uniq -c


rec  col

700 19
50 20
50 21
50 22
50 23
10 24
10 25
10 26
10 27
10 28
 9 29
 1 31
 1 32
 1 33
 1 35
 10 36
 27 42
```

Comment: could you clarify? my understanding is that you want those 700 lines with 19 fields written to a new file.. if so, use `awk -F, 'NF==19' x_orbit.txt > op_file` (there's a duplicate somewhere for this, will post if I find it)

Comment: thanks Sundeep for coming up. Your solution works but due to some constraints with my awk version i'm not getting some of it correct. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print > ("out_"(NF==19 ? NF : "other"))}' x_orbit.txt
```

Comment: Ed is a perennial resource of Unix knowledge. You have helped me many times. Thanks Ed